# bash: how does float arithmetic work?

Tags: bash, floating-point

I'm gonna tear my hair out: I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
then
    total=0
    IFS=' '
    while read one two; do
        total=$((total+two))
    done < $2
    echo  "Total: $total"
fi
```

Its supposed to add up my gas receipts I have saved in a file in this format:
`3/9/13 21.76`

output:

```
./getgas: line 9: 21.76: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".76")
```

I read online that its possible to do float math in bash, and I found an an example script that works and it has:

```
function float_eval()
{
    local stat=0
    local result=0.0
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        result=$(echo "scale=$float_scale; $*" | bc -q 2>/dev/null)
        stat=$?
        if [[ $stat -eq 0  &&  -z "$result" ]]; then stat=1; fi
    fi
    echo $result
    return $stat
}
```

which looks awesome, and runs no problem

WTF is going on here. I can easily do this is C but this crap is making me mad

EDIT: I don't anything about awk. It looks promising but I don't even know how to run those one-liners you guys posted

Comment: Bash supports only integer arithmetic, AFAIK. So you can use `bc` instead, if you need to, but be a little clever about it.  This looks like a job for `awk` though.

Comment: The second program uses "bc" (arbitrary precision calculater) to do the math

Comment: http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/Arithmetic-In-Bash.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{ sum += $2 } END { printf("Total: %.2f\n", sum); }' $2
```

Add up column 2 (that's the `$2` in the `awk` script) of the file named by shell script argument `$2` (rife with opportunities for confusion) and print the result at the end.

> I don't [know] anything about `awk`. It looks promising but I don't even know how to run those one-liners you guys posted.

In the context of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
then
    awk '{ sum += $2 } END { printf("Total: %.2f\n", sum); }' $2
else
    echo "Usage: $0 arg1 receipts-file" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

Or just write it on the command line, substituting the receipts file name for the `$2` after the `awk` command.  Or leave that blank and redirect from the file.  Or type the dates and values in.  Or, …

Your script demands two arguments, but doesn't use the first one, which is a bit puzzling.

As noted in the comments, you could simplify that to:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec awk '{ sum += $2 } END { printf("Total: %.2f\n", sum) }' "$@"
```

Or even use the shebang to full power:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ sum += $2 }
END { printf("Total: %.2f\n", sum) }
```

The kernel will execute `awk` for you, and that's the `awk` script written out as a two line program.  Of course, if `awk` is in `/bin/awk`, then you have to fix the shebang line; the shell looks in many places for `awk` and will probably find it.  So there are advantages to sticking with a shell script. Both these revisions simply sum what's on standard input if there are no files specified, or what is in all the files specified if there is one or more files specified on the command line.

Comment: sorry. That looks really nice. The rational behind adding the date to the file line is often when dealing with a bunch of receipts its very easy to miss one or double count one. Since I know I never fill up more than once a day (max is twice a week) I can keep track of a receipt by recording the date. The script was supposed to do more than just add up the numbers. This was really helpful BTW. Thank you.

Comment: The two columns in the input were easily understood; date and amount.  What I'm not sure is why you have the test `if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]` which checks that you call the script as: `your-script file1 receipts-file` and then doesn't use the first argument.  I'd reduce the whole thing to just the `awk` line with `"$@"` in place of the final `$2`.  That would add up standard input if you supply no files, or all the file names you specify on the command line.  I might slap an `exec` in front of the `awk` but often wouldn't bother.

Comment: sometimes I want to use the script adding up the number, other times I simply want to know if a receipt is already a part of the list. I couldn't think of a better way other than `script calc file`, `script add date price file`, as is happened in the past, I have 2 receipts from different days with the same price. IDK if it was smart, I certainly couldn't figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can only operate on integers. The example script you posted uses `bc` which is an arbitrary-precision calculation, included with most UNIX-like OS-es. So the script prepares an expression and pipes it to bc (the initial `scale=...` expression configures the number of significant digits `bc` should display.

A simplified example would be:

```
echo -e 'scale=2\n1.234+5.67\nquit' | bc
```

You could also use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 1.234+5.67}'
```

Comment: You're right, @glennjackman, `quit` is not neccessary in this case